# trying not to close the colorbox pop up when i click anywhere on the page

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am using colorbox plugin to open a popup.

PopUp contains the three radio buttons. Now what i want is not to close the popup when i click anywhere on the document unless or until i check one of the radio buttons.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Look at documentation: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

`overlayClose` - 
If false, disables closing Colorbox by clicking on the background overlay.

`escKey` - If false, will disable closing colorbox on 'esc' key press.

Changing globally:

```
$.colorbox.settings.overlayClose = false;
$.colorbox.settings.escKey = false;
```

**Added:**

As I can see debugging `colorbox`, changing this properties after `init` not affect current opened dialog, so you should add your own logic.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
$('.ui-widget-overlay').on("click", function() {
if(condition){
   $(window).colorbox.close();;
}
});
```